# 'Invalid input parameters' error when Opening URL in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI app. I have a button setup that is supposed to open **youtube.com**, but I am receiving an error message:

```
Failed to open URL www.youtube.com: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "invalid input parameters" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=invalid input parameters, _LSLine=230, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient openURL:options:completionHandler:]}
```

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            if let yourURL = URL(string: "www.youtube.com") {
                UIApplication.shared.open(yourURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }, label: {
            Text("Open URL")
                .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(16)
        })
    }
}
```

I also tried to use the Link modifier, but that didn't work.

Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

All I did was add 'https://' to my URL, then it worked.